# Can you disable DLC for a campaign?

Tags: steam, europa-universalis-iv

When you download a DLC, does the campaign creation screen allow you to choose whether to play the original version or with the DLC added? If it doesn't, can I disable DLC's somewhere else? And how would I go around doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Recommended Way**

You can disable DLC at the launcher. Simply click the DLC entry on the list on the DLC tab to add or remove the check-mark (Same goes for mods on the mods tab).

**Additional Way**

If you are using the steam version you can also disable DLC that way, Simply right click on the game in steam and go to properties -> DLC (tab). Uncheck the checkbox for the DLC you want to disable.

Comment: It's steam, and I should have mentioned that. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to disable in-game if the game offers that feature.  Disabling it in Steam can force you to re-download the content when you turn it back on.